# Angular directive that accept the 00.00,000 format

Tags: javascript, angular, regex, typescript, directive

I have an Angular Directive that should allow inputs only with the format `00.00,000`

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDecimalAmount]'
})
export class DecimalAmountDirective {

  private regex: RegExp = new RegExp(/^\d*\,?\d{0,2}$/g);
  private specialKeys: Array<string> = ['Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home', 'ArrowLeft', 'ArrowRight', 'Del', 'Delete'];
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }
  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (this.specialKeys.indexOf(event.key) !== -1) {
      return;
    }
    const current: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;
    const next: string = current.concat(event.key);
    if (next && !String(next).match(this.regex)) {
      event.preventDefault();

    }
  }
}
```

Currently, I use the regex `/^\d*\,?\d{0,2}$/g`, but it doesn't work because it helps me only with numbers with 2 decimals.

Answer (score 0):

To respect the format `00.00,000` you can use the following:

```
private regex: RegExp = new RegExp(^\d*\.?\d{0,2}\,?\d{0,3}$/g);
```

Take a look at the explanation https://regex101.com/r/w81Frk/1

Comment: this way only allow 3 decimals, and i need 2 decimals with comma and appear 3 digits after comma or not add dot.

Comment: You mean like this 00.00,000 ?

Comment: Yes Francesco. It´s possible some example, pelase

Comment: I just updated your question and my reply. Please let me know if helped. Thanks and sorry for the delay.